# Results on: (path/initial condition)-dependent variant of exponential map generates compactly supported diffeomorphisms

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, lie-groups, ds.dynamical-systems, differential-equations, flows

Let $M$ be a connected and simply connected Riemannian manifold, non-compact, and suppose that $\{V_p\}_{p \in M}$ is a family of vector fields on $M$ indexed by $M$.  Suppose moreover that the map
$$
p\to V_p(x),
$$
is smooth and define the differential equation
$$
f_t' = V_p(f_t) ,\, f_0=p. \qquad (*)
$$
So in $(*)$ there is an explicit dependence on $p$ both in the initial condition (IC) and in the "dynamics" of the ODE itself.  Therefore, let's relabel this explicit dependence on $p$ of a solution to $(*)$ by $f_{t,p}$.

Let $X$ be the collection of all compactly-supported smooth vector-fields on $M$ such that

- A solution $f_{t,p}$ exists up to time $1$ for each $p$,
- The map taking $(V_p)_{p \in M}$ to the time $1$ solution of $(*)$ is a diffeomorphism,
- $p\to V_p(x)$ *is non-constant* for at-least one value of $x\in M$.

Denote this latter map by $\widetilde{\operatorname{Exp}}:X\to \operatorname{Diff}_{c,0}(M)$.  It is known, see [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/358238/reconciling-some-result-about-the-exponential-map-the-chow-rashevskii-theorem) for references, that if there is no dependence on $p$ then $\operatorname{Exp}$ generates $\operatorname{Diff}_{c,0}(M)$.  Are such results known in this case, i.e.: where vector fields depend non-trivially on the ICs?

Comment: Just to be sure, what is $\mathrm{Diff}_{c,0}$?

Comment: It's the identity component of the space of $C^{\infty}$ diffeomorphisms with compact support (in the sense of A. Banyaga; namely that they are the identity outside some compact in M).

Comment: Thanks. Got it.  Here is another (dumb) question. Is $X$ nonempty?

Comment: Yes, ofcourse, we assume that to be the case (it can be shown also).